# LARAVEL: Left join group data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have two table in my database,  product category and subcategory. I want to list all my product category names and subcategory names with left join.
my query:

```
 $subcategory =DB::table('product_categories')->distinct('product_categories.categorie_name')
  ->select(array('product_categories.categorie_name','subcategory.sub_category_name'))
        ->leftJoin('subcategory', 'product_categories.product_category_id', '=', 'subcategory.product_category_id')
        ->get();
```

The data was listed this way:

```
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#288 (2) {
  ["categorie_name"]=>
  string(6) "Phones"
  ["sub_category_name"]=>
  string(5) "Nokia"
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#290 (2) {
  ["categorie_name"]=>
  string(6) "Phones"
  ["sub_category_name"]=>
  string(7) "Samsung"
}
```

You can see, the PHONE category have 2 subcategories, Nokia and Samsung, but the problem is that data is in another array key, is it possible to list the data's in this way:
Phones:
-Nokia,
-Samsung
So, the data is in the same array key, thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Lets use models instead of database tables.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductCategory extends Model
{
    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }
}

class SubCategory extends Model
{
    ...
}

ProductCategory::with('subCategory:sub_category_name')
    ->select('category_name')
    ->get();
```